# Load file during Unit Test in Unity3d's Unity Test Runner

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, nunit

Using Unity 2018.1.1f1 and Visual Studio Community 2017

I've been creating unit tests using unity's built in Test Runner.  In this particular unit test, I want to read a file's content into a string.  Without having to build a static path to the file (which will sit next to the unit test class itself), how can I reference it?

The folder structure looks like this:

```
Directory:
Assets/Plugins/MyTools/Common/Properties/_tests/

Files:
MyTools.Common.Properties.Tests.asmdef
PropertiesTests.cs
test.txt
test-prop-file.txt
```

The test and some output details:

```
namespace MyTools.Common.Properties.Tests {
    public class PropertiesTests {
        [Test]
        public void ParsePropsFile() {
            Debug.Log(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName());
            // MyTools.Common.Properties.Tests, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

            Debug.Log(GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Length);
            // 0

            Debug.Log(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames().Length);
            // 0
        }
    }
}
```

In visual studio, I've tried to set the properties (Build Action = Embedded Resource, and Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always) of test-prop-file.txt and test.txt but they do not seem to do anything.  Also, when I close VS and reopen it, these are set back to what they were before (None and Do Not Copy).  I've also tried other combos like Build Action = Resource or Content but still nothing.

So how can I go about loading these files in the unit test without referencing them directly with a static path like D:/Code/Unity/MyProject/Assets/Plugins/MyTools/Common/Properties/_tests/test.txt?

Comment: Not the best solution but you can do `TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory + "/../../Assets/Plugins/MyTools/Common/Properties/_tests/"`. You might need to add more or less `/../`

Answer (score 0):

The location of your current test assembly can be retrieved with:

```
TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory
```

(If I've remembered correctly - the middle 'CurrentContext' may not be necessary!)

Comment: For that I get: 

`D:/Code/Unity/MyProject/Library/ScriptAssemblies`


This contains a bunch of .dll files.  No additional .txt files in there.

Comment: Have you tried this with `Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always` and `Build Action=Content` (Or maybe a different build action?)